# how to replace &lt; and &#xd; in paylaod after data weave transform

Tags: mule-studio, dataweave

I am trying to replace an xml from variable got from data weave into another data weave xml  but I am getting xml with  special chars as below, when the variable is replaced in the transform instead of getting '<' .

```
&lt;pol:convictionCode>AC24&lt;/pol:convictionCode>&#xd;
  &lt;pol:date>28012019&lt;/pol:date>&#xd;
  &lt;pol:banLength>00&lt;/pol:banLength>&#xd;
```

I am trying  as below code but its not correct, getting error (org.mule.api.MessagingException: Execution of the expression).I also need to replace  with ''. Not sure how to replace both of them in one go. Highly appreciate any help.

```
payload.replaceAll("\\&lt;","<")
```

Comment: Are you in mule 4. That doesn't look like a data-weave expression. Also can you paste the expression that generates the invalid xml, looks like that text is xml escaped

Comment: that is not a data weave expression, its the generated xml.

Comment: I am adding the xml from data weave to a variable in one flow and calling the variable in another dataweave of another flow. The xml pasted above is the payload after replacing witht the variable in data weave. the variable is fine with < but only the payload from the transform comes like that.